# How can I grep sub string which is between a word and a tab space?

Tags: batch-file, unix, grep

I am working on a batch file and i have to extract the job name from the following line using GREP command.

```
E:\Source\TASK1.log:Name : SERVER/1234/JobDone_2X   UserId  AutoLogonUser Password
```

i have to get the output like

```
Name : SERVER/1234/JobDone_2X
```

What I have tried:

i have tried

```
rem grep -Po ("Name : ")(.*[^\t]) "Input.txt" > output.txt
```

but its not working.can you help me

Comment: To ensure that your question is propagated to the correct readership, could you please confirm by hovering over the batch-file tag whether it is appropriate for your question.

Comment: rem` = remarks. **remove the `rem`**.

Comment: Why do you have to use `grep` instead of a better suited tool like `sed` or `awk`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a batch file in Windows and the line you're after being the first line of input.txt:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set/P "_="<"input.txt"
(For /F %%A In ("%_:*:Name : =%") Do Echo=Name : %%A)>output.txt
```